# How to remove the backslash in string using regex in Java?

Tags: java, regex

How to remove the backslash in string using regex in Java?

For example:

```
hai how are\ you?
```

I want only:

```
hai how are you?
```

Answer (score 109, accepted):

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

or

```
str = str.replace("\\", "");
```

`replaceAll()` treats the first argument as a regex, so you have to double escape the backslash.  `replace()` treats it as a literal string, so you only have to escape it once.

Comment: Hi, if theres a scenario where 'hai \how are\ you?' , how can we write the regular expression to remvo the last '\' which will result to hai \how are you?

Comment: But that would remove all "\", what if you just want to remove one not double \\? So something like :\) becomes :\) but :\\ also becomes :\ ?

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use [String.replaceAll()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll)

```
 String foo = "hai how are\\ you?";
 String bar = foo.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

Comment: Umm ... is that correct?  Don't you need to escape the '\' twice?  Once for the literal string and once for the regex; e.g. `foo.replaceAll("\\\\", "")`

Answer (score -6):

String foo = "hai how are\ you?"; 
String bar = foo.replaceAll("\\", "");     Doesnt work
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException occurs.... Find out the reason!! @Alan has already answered.. good

String bar = foo.replace("\\", "");    Does work