# How to remove backslash from String in Java?

Tags: java, string

I have a string value that includes backslash character (`\`). My goal is to replace it with the character(`_`).

I did the following as per solution provided in this question [How to remove the backslash in string using regex in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242417/how-to-remove-the-backslash-in-string-using-regex-in-java)

`String x = "2\5\2017";
 x = x.replaceAll("\\\\", "_");`

but I am always getting (`27`) as a value of `x`. Note: there is unknown character between 2 and 7. In the console, I can see it as a small square.

Comment: Did you try both solutions ? ( `replaceAll` and `replace` ). PS : You need to escape the `\ ` in `x` too -> `String x = "2\\5\\2017";`

Comment: In string literals, the backslash is an escape character, meaning that `"2\5\2017"` is interpreted as 4 characters, the middle two of which have ASCII values `5` and `201` (as octal digits). You need to escape your backslashes in string literals: `"2\\5\\2017"`

Comment: @AxelH Yes I did both replace and replaceAll and I got the same result. The String value is coming from DB like this it is not hard coded value to add a double slash.

Comment: _I have a string value that includes backslash character (/). My goal is to replace it with the character(_)._ your example uses a different slash... "/" vs. "\"

Comment: Your problem is not in `replace` - but in the original string. (This is also mentioned by others). To confirm that - just try printing the original string - without applying any replace... see what happens.

Comment: @Salman Can you confirm that the value you have shown us in your example is the result of a `System.out.print(x);` If that's the case, then you String is correct, but since you have a an output `2##7` then I guess not. Then you should check your method to get that value because the problem come from the DB or the JDBC.

Comment: @AxelH and Plirkee,  you are correct the original value is missed up. I should manage to get data correctly from DB

Answer (score 5):

This is caused by you are not escaping your `\` in your `x`(`"2\5\2017"`), if your doesn't escape `\` in `x`, it will think `\5` and `\201` (*octal* will have 3 digits) will be **octal** number. so:

```
"2\5\2017"
```

will display as:

```
2??7
```

so you should **unescape** like @Harmlezz way.

Comment: String value is coming from DB as "2\5\2017" without double slash how to apply @Harmlezz solution to this case

Comment: @Salman do you mean that if you print out string value the moment it comes from Db then you get `2\5\2017` in your console and not something like  `2??7` (as @chengpohi mentions)? In that case your example is flawed.. cause "2\\5\\2017" prints out as `2\5\2017`....

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to redefine your input string to:

```
String x = "2\\5\\2017"
```

then the result of `x` would be:

```
2_5_2017
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use **" \\ "**  to add **" \ "** in your string. and then replace it with **" _ "**

`String x = "2\\5\\2017";
       x = x.replaceAll("\\\\", "_");`

" \ " is a special character ,to see "\" in our String we need to add one extra "\" like "\\" in a string.

learn more on  [Special Characters](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30241&seqNum=3)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by  Plirkee, AxelH and chengpohi, the original value is not correct.

We manage to get a different form from DB (2/5/2017) instead of (2\5\2017) and then the replaceAll works.